# Local push notifications wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, push-notification

Please turn me in right direction. I want to create local notifications for checking incoming messages from website.

I can't pay for the server, but does anybody knows how to create local push notifications server in wp7?

Comment: Do you just need notifications (Toasts), or also a Live Tile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a "local" push notification server. You could however use background agents to perform a similar task and use the [ShellToast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltoast%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and [ShellTile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) APIs to achieve a similar result.

There is a background agent sample on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Do you know how I can set timeout other than 30 min.?

Comment: The duration and interval for background agents is currently fixed as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: If I just reference ScheduledTaskAgent (not running) to my application then I cannot stop debugging when I press back button. How do I fix it?